# First two lines of Khalid - reasons song

Tags: meaning-in-context

The lines are: Evade my intellect ; Feed into my introspect. I understand what evade, feed and introspect mean. But I don't understand what he's trying to say with those complete sentences in sense of English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the poetic interpretation of song lyrics, which are typically much less restricted to normal English usage.

Comment: So this type of songs, of singers like Khalid, Tyga, Travis Scott etc. are hardly to full understand for non-native speakers, right?

Comment: "Feed into my introspect" is ungrammatical as **introspect** is not a noun but a verb (and sometimes an adjective).  The noun is **introspection**.

Comment: We can only tell you the literal or (standard) figurative meanings of the words. We cannot interpret them for you, as that would be off-topic for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

To **feed into** means "to contribute", especially in a way that makes something  more intense.

> The network's depiction of the migrants as an army of thugs feeds into the paranoia of a certain portion of the electorate.
>
> The Missouri River feeds into the Mississippi.

The depiction on TV contributes to their paranoia, making it more intense.

Water from the Missouri River flows into the Mississippi.